# Disable SIM PIN over MbnApi in dotnet

Tags: .net, sim-card

i try to Disable the PIN of some SIM-Cards in my Enterprise and need to do it remote. Because it's too many cards, i want to automate it. Long story short:

I want to disable the SIM-Pins over dotnet. I already use the MbnApi for reading the SIM-ICC etc. but i cannot get my hands on the PIN-Number. I know any PIN in respect to the SIM-ICC, but i don't know how to get an instance of IMbnPin.

How do instantiate IMbnPin?

Thanks in advance,

Alexander
-- Edit:

Below is my knowledge of the API so far. My Problem persists, i cannot find a Method that gives me an instance of IMbnPin. I looked into the API reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/api/mbnapi/nn-mbnapi-imbnpinmanager (this is for unmanaged c++) and stretched the good ol' search engines.

The Method IMbnInterface::QueryInterface is non-existent in managed Code/ C#.

```
    public static SimCard[] ReadDevices() {
        List<SimCard> sc = new List<SimCard>();
        SimCard temp = new SimCard();

        MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
        IMbnInterfaceManager infMgr = (IMbnInterfaceManager)mbnInfMgr;

        IMbnInterface[] interfaces = (IMbnInterface[])infMgr.GetInterfaces();
        foreach (IMbnInterface mobileInterface in interfaces)
        {
            temp = new SimCard();

            try {
                MBN_INTERFACE_CAPS caps = mobileInterface.GetInterfaceCapability();
                temp.Imei = caps.deviceID;

                IMbnSubscriberInformation iSubInf = mobileInterface.GetSubscriberInformation();
                temp.Icc = iSubInf.SimIccID;
                temp.Imsi = iSubInf.SubscriberID;

                MBN_PROVIDER provider = mobileInterface.GetHomeProvider();
                temp.Carrier = provider.providerName;

                MBN_READY_STATE readyState = mobileInterface.GetReadyState();
                IMbnRadio radio = (IMbnRadio)mobileInterface;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { //Ignore Errors
                StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(Path.GetTempPath() + "\\regat.txt");
                wr.Write(ex.ToString());
                wr.Flush();
                wr.Close();
            }
            finally { // Get minimal Information out of PIN-Locked SIM-Card
                if (temp != null &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp.Imei) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp.Icc)) {

                    sc.Add(temp);
                }

            }
        }
        return sc.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your source code look like?

Comment: As you can see, i tried some things with the MbnApi. I was unable to retrieve the Pin from the Device/ Sim-Card. I don't ask for a fully fledged solution, i just need to know how to enter the actual PIN and deactivate it with the MbnApi. I'd take any other solution now for that matter...